# Why does 子供たち mean children while 友達 can mean 1 friend?

Tags: suffixes, plural-suffixes

たち　is a **pluralizing** suffix. So, 猫たち means cat**s**, 子供たち　means **children** and 人たち　means **people**.

Why can 友達　mean 1 friend, even though there is the word 友　meaning **a** friend?

(I see that 達 in 友達 is not written using kana, unlike たち in, say, 猫たち. But originally the suffix used to be written as 達 even in words like 子供たち, didn't it?)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/does-%e5%8f%8b%e9%81%94-have-the-plural-marker-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a1-built-in

Comment: Because you always make _friends_. I'm joking.